# MySQL comparison of date to the max of a subquery that might return null

Tags: mysql, null, comparison, where-clause

I have a WHERE CLAUSE that looks like this:

```
t.triggered > (SELECT MAX(time_flag) FROM triggers)
```

When the subquery returns a value because there is one the whole query is executed normally.

When the subquery has no returned value the comparison is always false and no records are returned even though everything is greater than 'NULL'.

I read that 'NULL' is not appropriate for comparisons, so how can the query be written in order to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
t.triggered > COALESCE((SELECT MAX(time_flag) FROM triggers), '1900-01-01')
```

A predicate containing a `NULL` value, doesn't evaluate to either `true`, or `false`: it evaluates to `NULL`. Using [**`COALESCE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)  you can compare to a very old value in case the subquery returns `NULL` and hence return everything from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Replace NULL value with default value (some minimal date) in subquery using IFNULL or COALESCE functions:

t.triggered > (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(time_flag), '1000-01-01') FROM triggers)

Comment: Yes this is what @Giorgos Betsos recommended and it worked. Thanks for your time nevertheless